# Bindings in XCode 3.2.3

Tags: cocoa, xcode

I'm trying to follow step 1 of [this tutorial](http://www.cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000080.php), which was made for an older version of XCode than the one I'm using. I'm supposed to drag a connection from a green NSObjectController icon to a blue object icon, and select the "content" outlet. However when I try to do this, no outlets are showing. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should still be able to do this. Make sure the other steps are right too.

The crucial step is to declare the other object as an `IBOutlet` in the class interface and then make sure the two object types are correct in Interface Builder.